# Basic ideals exercise, and a question about notation definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

From this [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bht8Acb8BEEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction%20to%20algebraic%20geometry%20brendan&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjopcCWrJPNAhXjB8AKHZExBCEQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20algebraic%20geometry%20brendan&f=false).

> Given a finite set $\left\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_r\right\} \subset R$, the ideal $I$ generated by this set is denoted  $f_1, f_2, \ldots , f_r$ and consists of all the sums $f_1h_1 + f_2h_2 + ·· ·+ f_r h_r$ where the $h_j \in R$. (Showing this
>   defines an ideal is an exercise.)

My attempt:

Let $g_1, g_2 \in I$, I have to prove that $g_1 + g_2 = h_1 f_1 + \ldots h_r f_r, \; h_1, \ldots h_r \in R$, we have:

$$
g_i = h_1^i f_1 + \ldots h_r^i f_r \;\; ,h_j^i \in R , i \in \left\{1,2\right\}, j \in \left\{1, \ldots, r\right\} \Rightarrow g_1 + g_2 = \left(h_1^1 + h_1^2 \right) f_1 + \ldots \left(h_r^1 + h_r^2 \right) f_r \;\;
$$

But since $R$ is a ring we have $h_j^1 + h_j^2 \in R$ so we proved the first part.

Similarly if $h \in R, g \in I$ we have:

$$
hg = h h_1 f_1 + \ldots h h_r f_r = \left(h h_1 \right) f_1 + \ldots + \left( h h_r \right) f_r
$$

But $h h_j \in R \forall j \in \left\{1, \ldots r \right\}$.

Is such proof correct?

Related I have a question, from the same book sometimes it omits to specify the ring used to generate an ideal like in the algorithm 2.7.

> Fix a monomial order > on $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ and
>   nonzero polynomials $f_1,\ldots, f_r ∈ k[x_1, . . . , x_n]$. Given $g \in k[x_1, \ldots , x_n]$, we want
>   to determine whether $g \in  <f_1, \ldots, f_r> $

In situations like this it is assumed the ring is the set $k[x_1,\ldots x_n]$ right? I just find a bit unclear situations like this, because maybe the set $f_1,\ldots f_n$ could generate a closed subset of the ring I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Your proof is correct. I don't understand your second question, haven't you explicitly stated that you are talking about $k[x_1,x_2,...x_n]$?

Comment: I stated what $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is, I also stated what $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ are, but since to define an ideal I need a ring, but in my example there's no reference between $g \in <f_1,\ldots,f_r>$ and which ring is using, how can I be sure in that case the $<f_1,\ldots,f_r>$ spans $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

Comment: But $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a ring, so we are talking about the ideal generated by $f_1, f_2,\ldots,f_n$ in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. What do you have in mind when you say span?